# Select all from first table and order by Count(id) from second table where second.value = 1

Tags: mysql, laravel, pdo, eloquent, table-relationships

There are two table **videos** and **reactions**.

[image]

I want to sort videos by likes descending.
**reactions** table is same for likes and dislikes. (I did not want to create two different tables for likes and dislikes).
There is **reaction** column in the **reactions** table where `reaction = 1`  means **likes**, `reaction = 2`  means **disslikes**

The thing is that my code without `where('reactions.reaction', 1)` returns all videos sorted by total reactions `(likes + disslikes)` and I need to sort by only `likes`.

If add **where('reactions.reaction', 1)** then my query will returns only videos with likes instead of all the videos.

I want to get all videos from the table sorted by likes and not just liked videos.
What should I do?

```
$videos = Video::select('videos.id', DB::raw('count(reactions.id) as total'))
->leftJoin('reactions', 'reactions.at_video', '=', 'videos.id')
// ->where('reactions.reaction', 1) // I need this for only reactions
->groupBy('videos.id')
->orderBy('total', 'DESC')
->get();

dd($videos);
```

Comment: I think you should use join instead of left join, so if a video does not have any reactions the query will not select them.

Comment: LEFT JOIN is right way becouse of as we can read LEFT JOIN keyword returns all records from the left table (table1), and the matching records from the right table (table2).  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: okay than does this help you
->where(function ($q){ $q->where('reactions.reaction', 1)->orWhereNull(''reactions.reaction');})

Comment: Thanks man. You saved me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Massive thanks to **fake97** for the solution.

I needed to change `->where('reactions.reaction', 1)`
To `>where(function ($q){ $q->where('reactions.reaction', 1)->orWhereNull(''reactions.reaction');})`

**See the code below**

```
$videos = Video::select('videos.id', DB::raw('count(reactions.id) as total'))
->leftJoin('reactions', 'reactions.at_video', '=', 'videos.id')
->where(function ($q){ 
  $q->where('reactions.reaction', 1)->orWhereNull('reactions.reaction');
})
->groupBy('videos.id')
->orderBy('total', 'DESC')
->get();
      
dd($videos);
```